# Anaconda does not appear to have installed properly

Tags: python, anaconda

When I install Anaconda, it yields a lot of uninstalled strange applications. The image arrows point to a couple of those. Didn't see those yesterday. Here is what I see when I open Anaconda:

[Junk Apps/Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKSGJ.png)

I tried Jupyter Notebook and it seems to come up properly. It's just the list of apps that is cluttered up.

Comment: It's not a bug or mistake. It's a suggested list for you to install if you wish to. I have this in my anaconda too

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.